# sequelize findOrCreate with include association

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

Using sequelize, I have two models with associations:

```
var Assessment = sequelize.define("Assessment", {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});

var User = sequelize.define("User", {
  sid: DataTypes.STRING
});

Assessment.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Assessment);
```

After some application logic, I have a `User`:

```
User.findOrCreate( { where: {sid: "123"} } ).spread(function (user, created) {
  // user is a User
});
```

At this point, I cannot get sequelize to associate the User as part of a `Assessment.findOrCreate`.  This code will create a new Assessment record in the database (if one does not exist), but it will **not** include the User key as part of the record (instead it's just NULL):

```
Assessment.findOrCreate( {
  where: { },
  include: [ { model: User, where: user.primaryKeyValues } ]
} ).spread( function (assessment, created) {
  // ...
});
```

---

I have a workaround working by adding:

```
assessment.setUser(user).then( function(assessment) {
   ...
});
```

...however, this results in a SQL UPDATE that should just be part of creating the record.  I'm fairly certain there should be way to do this, but unable to find anything in the docs/so/etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try this: You'd need to set the `User` primary key reference into the created assessment.

```
Assessment.findOrCreate( {
  where: { UserId: user.id },
  include: [ User ]
} ).spread( function (assessment, created) {
  // assessment should contain a User property with the previously found / created user
});
```